# QGIS 2.6 can't reload Python plugins

Tags: qgis-plugins, ubuntu, cache, qgis-2.6

Im using QGIS 2.6 on Ubuntu 14.04. Suddenly a strange caching behaviour appeard in QGIS. When I change the plugin code and try to reload it with for example the Plugin Reloader plugin or when I reload it manually nothing happens. Even after a QGIS restart there is still the old code in the cache. At the moment the only possibility to get the new code into QGIS is to delete my plugin out of the QGIS folder, restart QGIS, put my plugin folder into python/plugins and reload the plugin via Plugin Reloader.

I tried to reload it with `qgis.utils.reloadPlugin('MyPlugin')` and also with

```
qgis.utils.unloadPlugin('MyPlugin')
True
qgis.utils.loadPlugin('MyPlugin')
True
qgis.utils.startPlugin('MyPlugin')
```

The functions returning a `True` value but nothing happens.

Any ideas what is causing this cache behaviour?

Comment: Can't say the same for Ubuntu as I use Windows but what I did when I edited my plugin was to recompile it and then copy/paste the folder into the QGIS folder (this replaces the old version of the plugin). This avoids having to use the Plugin Reloader as QGIS loads the plugin on restart. But as I say, it's probably different for Ubuntu.

Comment: If I recompile it and copy and paste it into the folder it works if I restart Qgis as well, which I try to avoid. Before I reloaded the plugin with the function `qgis.utils.reloadPlugin('PluginName'). But suddenly it stopped working.

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't know you want to avoid that method. It is strange that it stops working all of a sudden. Have you tried the good old-fashioned restarting your computer? Otherwise hopefully others will advise on this weird behavour.

Comment: Yes I tried it as well ;). But I have this error since a couple days and I can't find a solution... But thank you for your help!

Comment: I've deleted everything inside the .qgis2 folder and reinstalled qgis. Now it is working again...

Comment: Glad it's working again. Weird though, hopefully it won't happen again!